# Using expect to login, copy file and bounce server

Tags: bash, shell

i need to login to remote machine,stop server,copy file from one folder and then start server.
i have written script but it seems this is not working after login.

```
spawn ssh papp95@bt781.com
expect "password"
send "12345\r"
interact return
cp p1 p2
stopserver
statserver
```

i am not able to progress further,any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can't you put a public key on the machine and then use `ssh` directly rather than use expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ever wroten a `wise_ssh` function with `expect` to replace `sshpass`:

```
function wise_ssh
{
    passwd=$1
    cmd=${@:2}
    expect -c "set timeout 5;
            spawn ${cmd};
            expect *assword:*;
            send ${passwd}\r;
            interact;"
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
wise_ssh 12345 ssh papp95@bt781.com "cp p1 p2"
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you want execute more than one command remotely, just append to `"cp p1 p2"`, such as `wise_ssh 12345 ssh papp95@bt781.com "cp p1 p2;stopserver;startserver"`

Comment: i am getting invalid command issue when i am using semicolon for multiple commands

Comment: sorry, forget to mention that you add quotes when use multiple commands: `wise_ssh 12345 ssh papp95@bt781.com "\"cp p1 p2;stopserver;startserver\""`